# Some C# code cause to "Server Busy" error message

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, vsto

The following code:

(Calling to async method that return Task)

```
...
        Task<int> taskInt = Globals.ThisAddIn._DAL.InsertTestAceQL();
        int resInt = taskInt.Result;
        MessageBox.Show("resInt= " + resInt.ToString());
...
        public async Task<int> InsertTestAceQL()
        {
            int res = int.MinValue;
            try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.AceQLTst2 VALUES ('From Visio')";

                AceQLCommand command = new AceQLCommand(sql, AceQLConn().Result);
                try
                {
                    res = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                catch (AceQLException ex)
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.HandleException(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Globals.ThisAddIn.HandleException(ex.Message);
            }

            return res;
        }
...
```

cause to the following error message:

And the code is go stuck.

[image: Server Busy]

**Someone know something please?**

Comment: Try restarting your Server and running the code again.

Comment: `.Result` is the wrong way to access the result of an async operation. One of those is causing a deadlock.

Comment: @Arsen, It's not help. BTW, the same code working good from "Console Application" but didn't work well from "Class Library" Visio Add-ins.

Comment: @GalTzemach, sorry, the message "...busy" lead me to think that application hanging could be the main reason. Is your test connection to DB working as expected? Did you also tried to put some real int number instead of `int.MinValue`? Are you able to get some values from DB with a query or only inserting fails? Try answering these questions, hope they can help.

Comment: @Arsen, After few clicks on "Retry" button everything was done well.

Comment: @madreflection, But, exactly the same code work well from other place in my code. 
The error message appear only when i try this during UI thread working. 
So, how can i call to async method, wait and get a some result?

Comment: *"The error message appear only when i try this during UI thread working"* -- That's a *very* different context and that difference is what's causing the problem. The point is that you need to do proper `await`s to get the result. If you're not in an `async`-marked method, you'll need to do some research. Calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` may still cause a deadlock depending on what else is scheduled on the thread. Read everything you can about async by [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No C# code is causing any server to be busy.

What's happening is that the UI is blocked by this code:

```
int resInt = taskInt.Result;
```

and Windows is tellying you that the application is busy and is not responding - blocked UI.

Comment: Thanks. So, what is the right way to call and wait to result of async method from non async (regular) method?

Comment: In an `async` method and with `await`. And al `await`s in `InsertTestAceQL` should have `ConfigureAwait(false)`.